# Image not locking at center in open flow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coverflow

I am using open flow library in my project.When I scroll the image it does get in center.
Can anybody tell me which method to modify in open flow files to do it correct or some another approach.

Attached the screen shot describing what the exactly problem is:-It is shifting towards left(not in center).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the coverflow view is not sized correctly, it should be 320px wide and have a left position of 0.0

Comment: can you please tell me where I should check these values in the open flow library(means which file or which method should I look).